# Device preference between two certificates for encryption

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, self-signed, self-signed-certificate

I want to create a root ca certificate and then a self signed certificate for google.com signed with my own root ca (with a different public key).

And I install both in my device

Now, if I type google.com in my browser, which certificate does the device use for encryption?

(Given that the google.com certificate has already been signed by a valid CA)

If the device uses the website's official certificate, how can I force it to use my own certificate?

Comment: That’s not possible. The SSL certificate‘s private key must be installed  on the server, not the client.